# str not converting to float/int because its not ignoring '\n' like it should for a number- python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, floating-point, integer

I'm doing some self study and came across this problem.

```
def main():

    golf = open('golf.txt','w')

    name = not('end')

    while name != 'end':
        name = input("Enter players name or 'end'  to quit ")
        score = float(input('Enter score '))
    
        golf.write(name + '\n')
        golf.write(str(score) +'\n')
        name = input("Enter players name or 'end'  to quit ")
    
    golf.close()

    golf=open('golf.txt','r')

    name = golf.readline()

    while name !='':
        score = float(golf.readline()) #ValueError#
        name = name.rstrip('\n')
    
    print(name,': ',score)
    golf.close()

main()

Enter players name or 'end'  to quit ted
Enter score 100
Enter players name or 'end'  to quit end
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-b71bcadf2947> in <module>
     27     golf.close()
     28 
---> 29 main()
     30 
     31 

<ipython-input-6-b71bcadf2947> in main()
     21 
     22     while name !='':
---> 23         score = float(golf.readline())
     24         name = name.rstrip('\n')
     25 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 

********changed float to int below**********

Enter players name or 'end'  to quit ted
Enter score 100
Enter players name or 'end'  to quit end
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-8bffc375cbfa> in <module>
     27     golf.close()
     28 
---> 29 main()
     30 
     31 

<ipython-input-7-8bffc375cbfa> in main()
     21 
     22     while name !='':
---> 23         score = int(golf.readline())
     24         name = name.rstrip('\n')
     25 

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '100.0\n'
```

I'm getting a ValueError for this and i dont understand. If i change float to int it gives me more of idea of what exactly it cant convert: '10\n'. it seems to not be ignoring the escape like it should for a number. tried refreshing my kernel and everything still nothing. i shouldn't have to rstrip a string number...

Comment: have you tried `.replace("\n", "")`

Comment: not familiar with that.. i'm sure it would work like stripping '\n' would. But that doesn't answer the question of why i'm getting this flag in the first place. Is it something i'm doing that's provoking this? Just trying to figure that out so it doesn't happen again.

Comment: Post the full traceback so I can help you more.

Comment: posted for both float and int

Comment: `int` and `float` both accept and ignore all leading and trailing whitespace. Whatever is going wrong, it's not the newline.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this and post if you have any more errors or questions

```py
def main():
    name = ""
    with open("golf.txt", "w") as golf:
        while name != "end":
            name = input("Enter player's name or 'end' to quit: ")
            if name != "end":
                score = input("Enter score: ")
    
                golf.write(name + "\n")
                golf.write(score + "\n")
    
    with open("golf.txt") as golf:
        text = golf.read().split("\n")

    for i in range(0, len(text), 2):
        try:
            name = text[i]
            score = text[i+1]
        except IndexError:
            break
        print(f"{name}: {score}")


main()
```

---

**f-strings**

These are used so you can pass variables inside strings in python.
f-strings were introduced in python 3.6 and you can write them like this

```py
string = f"Something here {variable}"

# You can also do the same in older versions by using '.format()'
string = "Something here {}".format(variable)
```

[Here is a link to read more about string formatting and f-strings from "RealPython"](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

---

You can read about **with** from a lot of sources.

[Here is a link to read about the **with** keyword from "GeeksforGeeks"](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/with-statement-in-python/)

---

**try/except**

`try/except` blocks catch errors that might happen and executes code when that error occurs. So an `IndexError` will occur when `i+1` is larger than `len(text)`, so to catch that I used a `try/except` block.

[Here is a link to read more about it from "W3Schools"](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp)

---

**break**

`break` is used when you want to stop running a loop prematurely without executing the lines after the `break` statement. It's used here because when the `IndexError` happens, it means that the list is parsed and that we can't print the score or the name, so we need to exit the loop.

[Here is a link to read more about it from "Programiz"](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue)

---

Also the `ValueError` doesn't happen anymore, because the `score` variable will always be a string, since no calculations are made with it. However, you could convert it into a float after creating the `text` variable.

Comment: Keep in mind that i am just learning python.. so i'm not familiar with anything advanced to solve this problem. This answer is laid out the same way as Tony Gaddis starting out with python ch. 6 ed 4 except i added a sentinel and he used an input to ask a user to go again. it worked for him. so it should work.. although i know its not as efficient as it can be.

Comment: Oh no problem, I am also a beginner. Maybe you could try this example? Also what version of Python are you using?

Comment: this did work however not completely  it makes me put in a score after i put end instead of just stopping like it should and displaying the name and score. a former edition of python, or stuff i haven't learned but i'm not sure whats a few things are on here.. like 'with' 'f' '{}''break... and although i appreciate your help i still don't understand why my solution doesn't work. its frustrating lol.

Comment: i'm using 3.7.4

Comment: Great, then this should work for you. I'll edit my answer to explain some things.